# Range<Date> issue

Tags: java, android, guava

I have successfully been able to retrieve all data for a point, but i am currently trying to retrieve data between a date range.  I'm having issues specifying the Range.  See code below.  I think that everything is fine until the "dateRange.lowerEndpoint() = lowerDate;  This is where i'm unsure.  I would appreciate any help in getting this straightened out.

```
    public class GetDataAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List> {
List<Value> dataValues = null;

@Override
protected List doInBackground(String... point) {

   // Adjust these variables accordingly
   final EmailAddress EMAIL_ADDRESS = CommonFactory.createEmailAddress("XXXX@gmail.com");
   final String ACCESS_KEY = "XXXX";
   final UrlContainer INSTANCE_URL = UrlContainer.getInstance("XXXX.appspot.com");

   Range<Date> dateRange = null;
   Date lowerDate = new Date(1398297720);
   Date upperDate = new Date(1395273970);

   dateRange.lowerEndpoint() = lowerDate; // <---- I know this is wrong.  Not sure of correct code.
   dateRange.upperEndpoint() = upperDate; // <---- I know this is wrong.  Not sure of correct code.


   final Server SERVER = ServerFactory.getInstance(INSTANCE_URL);
   String pointName[] = point;

   PointHelper pointHelper = HelperFactory.getPointHelper(SERVER, EMAIL_ADDRESS, ACCESS_KEY);
   boolean pointExists = pointHelper.pointExists(pointName[0]);
   List<Value> recordedValues = null;
   if (pointExists) {
       ValueHelper valueHelper = HelperFactory.getValueHelper(SERVER, EMAIL_ADDRESS, ACCESS_KEY);
       recordedValues = valueHelper.getSeries(pointName[0], dateRange);
   }
   return recordedValues;   }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List result) {
    dataValues = result;
    Value currentValue;
    Double currentDouble;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataValues.size(); i++) {
        Log.e("Log", String.valueOf(dataValues.get(i)));
        Value mValue = dataValues.get(i);
        Double mDouble = mValue.getDoubleValue();
        Date mDate = mValue.getTimestamp();
        Log.e("Double Value", String.valueOf(mDouble));
        Log.e("Timestamp", String.valueOf(mDate));
        currentValue = dataValues.get(0);
        currentDouble = currentValue.getDoubleValue();
    }
} }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you want:

```
Range<Date> dateRange = Range.closed(lowerDate, upperDate);
```

(Assuming you do want both the lower date and the upper date included in the range.)

Also, you say you know that `dateRange.lowerEndpoint() = lowerDate;` is wrong, but in case it helps I'll explain what's wrong with it:

- First, you initialize `dateRange` to `null`. You have to actually create an object before you can do anything with it, so even if it were possible to call methods to set the lower and upper endpoints on a range (or assign fields), you can't do it if you don't create the object first. You'll get `NullPointerException`.
- Second, `lowerEndpoint()` and `upperEndpoint()` are methods. They aren't fields, and you can't assign to them.
- Finally, `Range` is an *immutable* type. Once a `Range` is created, it can't be changed. You appear to be attempting to use it as if it's a *mutable* type where you first create a range of nothing and then alter it to have the properties you want. `Range` requires that everything be specified up front, when you create it.